# How can I watch TED videos offline on Android?

Tags: video, offline

I'm looking for a way of subscribing to and watching [TED](http://www.ted.com/) talk videos on the HTC Desire, but I want support for off-line viewing.

The [Mother TED](http://www.motherapp.com/en/showcase/motherted) app seems to require an active network connection, which isn't suitable since I want to be able to watch videos on the underground.

There's an RSS feed of the mp4 videos [here](http://feeds.feedburner.com/TEDTalks_video) - is there anything like Google Listen that supports mp4 video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [BeyondPod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mobi.beyondpod) (the full version) to watch TED Talks all the time.  It pulls in a list of the videos from the feed and you can choose to download which ever ones you want and then play them right in BeyondPod.  There is no data connection required.

Answer (score 2):

The official app for TED Conferences is what I use. It has saving and sharing capabilities.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ted.android

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [doubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/).  doubleTwist will re-encode any video to be suitable for your device, simply by dragging the video onto your device listed in the program.

doubleTwist has built-in functionality for subscribing to podcasts, but I use iTunes to organize podcasts, then use doubleTwist to send the content to, and play the content on, my HTC Hero.

Answer (score 1):

As of this date, simply download the official TED app and select the talk you like to view offline. Then tap the download icon to the top-right corner to download. You can then play the downloaded videos offline from `My Talks` tab.

If you are a kind of person who like to play the videos at higher speed, you can get apps that support fast playback such as `VLC for Android` or `Dice Player`. Since all the downloaded files are stored in `/sdcard/Android/data/com.ted.android/files/`, you can point the video player to that path.

Hope this helps someone.